# Creating a Winform application for installing a website using msdeploy?

Tags: winforms, web-deployment

I am creating a winform application for deploying a website to IIS 7 using msdeploy. I have three textboxes on my form named txtName, txtPort and txtSelectedFile. The input in these two textboxes is used to create command.
Following is the string concatenation:

```
string command = "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\IIS\\Microsoft Web Deploy\\msdeploy.exe\" -verb:sync 
                 -presync:runCommand=\"md %SystemDrive%\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\" + txtName.Text.Trim() + 
                 " & %systemroot%\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd add site /name:" + txtName.Text.Trim() + 
                 " /id:22 /bindings:http/*:" + txtPort.Text.Trim() + ": /physicalPath:%SystemDrive%\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\" + 
                 txtName.Text.Trim() + " \" -source:package=" + txtSelectedFile.Text + 
                 " -dest:contentPath=%SystemDrive%\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\" + txtName.Text.Trim();
```

I am using ProcessStartInfo to run the command. However the website does not get installed.
However if I put a debugger and capture the text in the variable named command and execute it manually by using the command prompt, the website gets deployed.